# RE-order array elements for html dependency

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have some HTML formatting on my front end template that depends on the result of a foreach loop on an array, in this example in order to get the right formatting it expects the order of the panel_type_id to be 4,6,3 otherwise it builds the formatting wrong.

If the panels are added in the order of 4,6,3 then there's no problem.

Is there a way to reorder the array on load so that no matter what it follows this order?

```
  <div class="row middle">
  <?php foreach($panelResult as $PR): ?>
  <?php if($PR['panel_type_id'] == 4){ ?>
  <!-- Left -->
  <div class="col-lg-6"  >
    <div class="row" style="height:50%; padding-bottom: 15px;">
        <div class="col-lg-12" style="height:100%;">
            <div style="/*background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);*/ height: 100%; ">
        <?php echo $PR['content']?>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <?php } elseif($PR['panel_type_id'] == 6){?>
    <div class="row" style="height:50%; padding-top: 15px;">
        <div class="col-lg-12" style="height:100%;">
            <div style="/*background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);*/ height: 100%;">
          <?php echo $PR['content']?>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } elseif($PR['panel_type_id'] == 3){?>
  <div class="col-lg-6" >
        <div style="/*background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);*/ height: 100%; ">
        <?php echo $PR['content']?>
      </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div><!--end row middle-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and define your own function.

Consider the following:

```
$panelResult = array(["panel_type_id" => 3, "content" => "CCC"], ["panel_type_id" => 4, "content" => "BBB"], ["panel_type_id" => 6, "content" => "AAA"]);

function cmp($a, $b) {
    $goodOrder = [4,6,3];
    return array_search($a["panel_type_id"], $goodOrder) - array_search($b["panel_type_id"], $goodOrder);
}

usort($panelResult, "cmp");
```

Now the order of `$panelResult` will be: `4, 6, 3` so you just keep using your original code

Comment: So I would just change your example from id to panel_type_id and data to content?

Comment: Yes - will update my post with your var names. This is just example - notice that in your code you don't need to have `Data` at all...

Comment: Oh oh, I see now! So will I still have a foreach though? How exactly will I incorporate that into my loop?

Comment: This should come before the `for` loop - it will modify the array and then you can continue as your current code - I answered generally about re-ordering array regardless of your code

Comment: Ok, I was thinking I would have to do this within a for loop on my current array to build the key/index relationship and then use the new array in my formatting loop but maybe I'm confused

Comment: Just call `usort` on your `$panelResult` with newly-define-compare-function after change `id` to `panel_type_id`. Then do all your code as post here

Comment: So your example works with my formatting and re-ordering but the only thing I'm missing is how to replace your hard-coded array with the actual $panelResult call from my database file?

Comment: In other words, $panelResult is set by the query in my included file so all I need to do here is replace the hard coded $panelResult array with a call to that variable as an array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186498/discussion-between-david-winder-and-tom-n).